# Java: Calculate more than 2 numbers in one row with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, calculator

Can anyone help me with this code? I want to calculate element 0 in an array with the operator in the element 0 in an other array with the element 1 in the first array with a for-loop. It should be possible calculate more than 2 number. sorry for bad english.

Here the code:

```
package rechnerparser;
import java.util.*;

public class RechnerParser
{
    public static String rechnung,
                         regexCheck = "[\\+\\-\\*/]";

    public static float ergebnis;
    public static int anzahlOperator, anzahlZahlen;

    public static String[] Zeichenkette, operatoren;
    public static float[] konventiert;

    public static Scanner eingabe = new Scanner (System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Geben Sie Ihre Rechnung auf einer Zeile ein z.B. 4+7/8 [+, -, *, /]");
        rechnung = eingabe.next();

        Zeichenkette = rechnung.split(regexCheck);   //save the numbers in the array "Zeichenkette"
        operatoren = rechnung.replaceAll("[\\da-zA-Z]","").split("");  //save the operator (+, -, *, /)in the array "operatoren"
        konventiert = new float[Zeichenkette.length];

        int i = 0;
        while(i < Zeichenkette.length) //convert the numbers from string array to float array
        {
            konventiert[i] = Float.parseFloat(Zeichenkette[i]);
            i++;
        }



        for (int a = 0; a < konventiert.length; a++)
        {
            ergebnis = konventiert[a] operatoren[a] (a++) konventiert[a]; //not working
////////////konventiert[0] operatoren[0]       konventiert[1]
//example:       5              +                  4           = 9
        }

        /*
        if(operatoren[0].contains("+"))                 //only with 2 numbers
        {
            ergebnis = konventiert[0] + konventiert[1];
        }
        else if(operatoren[0].contains("-"))
        {
            ergebnis = konventiert[0] - konventiert[1]; 
        }
        else if(operatoren[0].contains("*"))
        {
            ergebnis = konventiert[0] * konventiert[1];
        }
        else if(operatoren[0].contains("/"))
        {
            ergebnis = konventiert[0] / konventiert[1];
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Falsches Format.");
        }
        */

        System.out.println(ergebnis);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`operatoren[a]` is a String value, not a Java operator.

```
for (int i = 0; i < konventiert.length - 1; i++) {
    switch (operatoren[i]) {
        case "*":
            result[i] = konventiert[i] * konventiert[i + 1];
            break;
        // more case statements
        default:
            // error
    }
}
```